# Fragment Tabhost Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No tab known for tag null When Internet Connection not available

Tags: android, tabs

I Am first checking the internet connection and after that I am starting my Activity and I face this problem when I use the Tab Host.

I am also put my adding tab host code in the try catch but it don't even catch the exception.

XML Code:

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#999999"

    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0" />
</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

My java Code

```
    cd = new ConnectionDetector(Alumni_MainActivity.this);
    // Check if Internet present
   if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
       // Internet Connection is not present
       alert.showAlertDialog(Alumni_MainActivity.this,
               "Internet Connection Error",
               "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
       // stop executing code by return
       return;
   }





try {
    tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.fragment_container);    



        addTab("Chat", R.drawable.chaticon, ChatRoom.class, tabHost,null);
        addTab("Contacts", R.drawable.contacticon, Memeber_view.class, tabHost, null);
        addTab("Gallery", R.drawable.gallery, Galler_View.class, tabHost, null);

        addTab("Event", R.drawable.event, EventList.class, tabHost,null);  
        addTab("More", R.drawable.moreicon, More.class, tabHost,null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Error:**
`08-20 10:02:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13462): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-20 10:02:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13462): java.lang.IllegalStateException: No tab known for tag null
08-20 10:02:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13462):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.doTabChanged(FragmentTabHost.java:330)
08-20 10:02:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13462):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost.onAttachedToWindow(FragmentTabHost.java:280)
08-20 10:02:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13462):    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:11988)
08-20 10:02:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13462):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2495)
08-20 10:02:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13462):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2502)
08-20 10:02:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13462):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2502)
08-20 10:02:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13462):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2502)
08-20 10:02:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13462):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:2502)
08-20 10:02:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13462):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1363)
08-20 10:02:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13462):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1139)
08-20 10:02:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13462):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4879)
08-20 10:02:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13462):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
08-20 10:02:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13462):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
08-20 10:02:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13462):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:548)
08-20 10:02:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13462):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
08-20 10:02:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13462):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-20 10:02:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13462):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-20 10:02:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13462):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
08-20 10:02:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13462):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5311)
08-20 10:02:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13462):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-20 10:02:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13462):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-20 10:02:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13462):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
08-20 10:02:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13462):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
08-20 10:02:04.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13462):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Please help me I am struck.

Thanks in Advance!!